# Persist users across containers

Tags: docker, rstudio-server

For the main RStudio Docker image the user/password information lives in the container. To create a new user you need to run `adduser` inside the container, see: https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Using-the-RStudio-image#multiple-users. This is an issue when updating to a new container as obviously the `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, etc. would not persist across containers. I was thinking of mounting the files to the host like so

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 \
-v $(pwd)/passwd:/etc/passwd \
-v $(pwd)/shadow:/etc/shadow \
... rocker/rstudio
```

But I'm unsure if the files associated with the system users should be exposed from the container to the host. Is it better to maintain a separate image built on top of `rocker/rstudio` with the users added, or is there something else better?

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for creating a new image with all the users you need. That's the easiest to redeploy. Mounting the files from the host risks showing system files in the image with the wrong ownership. If you need to be able to adjust users on the fly, then a volume just for these files (not mapped from the host) may work, but you'll also want home directories and probably need to mount the entire /etc to avoid inode issues from mounting individual files.

Answer (score 0):

i understand, that was not the question - but the reason its so hard to do what you are trying is - because its the wrong way to go with that.

You can fiddle your way around it, using some kind of PAM plugin to move some few users ( from your app ) to a different auth-plugin, which also can use a file for defintion, like /etc/rstudio_users - very similar as it is done with stfp and the ftp users. You can then safely share this file across the containers without being in the horrible stop sharing all users, also the system users, which will be the shutdown of you initial concept at some point anyway.

If you want this to be done right, use something like LDAP to share authentication data properly